# Pairs from a directed acyclic Neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a DAG which for the most part is a tree... but there are a few cycles in it. I mention it in case it matters.

I have to translate the graph into pairs of relations.  If:

```
A -> B
     C
     D -> 1
          2 -> X
               Y
```

Then I would produce ArB, ArC, arD, Dr1, Dr2, 2rX, 2rY, where r is some relationship information (in other words, the query cannot totally ignore it.)

Also, in my graph, node A has many cousins, so I need to 'anchor' my query to A.

My current attempt generates all possible pairs, so I get many unhelpful pairs such as ArY since A can eventually traverse to Y.

What is a query that starts (or ends) with A, that returns a list of pairs?  I don't want to query Neo individually for each node - I want to get the list in one shot if possible.

The query would be great, doc pages that explain would be great. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** Here's what I have so far, using Frobber's post as inspiration:

```
1. MATCH p=(n {id:"some_id"})-[*]->(m)
2. WITH DISTINCT(NODES(p)) as zoot
3. MATCH (x)-[r]->(y)
4. WHERE x IN zoot AND y IN zoot
5. RETURN DISTINCT x, TYPE(r) as r, y
```

Where in line 1, I make a path that includes all the nodes under the one I care about.

In line 2, I start a new match that is intended to return my pairs

Line 3, I convert the path of nodes to a collection of nodes

Line 4, I accept only x and y nodes that were scooped up the first match. I am not sure why I have to include y in the condition, but it seems to matter.

Line 5, I return the results. I do not know why I need a `distinct` here. I thought the one on line 3 would do the trick.

So far, this is working for me. I have no insight into its performance in a large graph.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach to try - this query is modeled off of the [sample matrix data you can find online](http://console.neo4j.org/) so you can play with it before adapting it to your schema.

```
MATCH p=(n:Crew)-[r:KNOWS*]-m
WHERE n.name='Neo'
WITH p, length(nodes(p)) AS nCount, length(relationships(p)) AS rCount
RETURN nodes(p)[nCount-2], relationships(p)[rCount-1], nodes(p)[nCount-1];
ORDER BY length(p) ASC;
```

A couple of notes about what's going on here:

1. Consider the "Neo" node (n.name="Neo") to be your "A" here.  You're rooting this path traversal in some particular node you pick out.
2. We're matching paths, not nodes or edges.
3. We're going through all paths rooted at the `A` node, ordering by path length.  This gets the near nodes before the distant nodes.
4. For each path we find, we're looking at the nodes and relationships in the path, and then returning the last pair.  The second-to-last node (`nodes(p)[nCount-2]`) and the last relationship in the path (`relationships(p)[rCount-1]`).

This query basically returns the node, the relationship, and the connected node showing that you can get those items; from there you just customize the query to pull out whatever about those nodes/rels you might need pursuant to your schema.

The basic formula starts with matching `p=(someNode {startingPoint: "A"})-[r:*]->(otherStuff)`; from there it's just processing paths as you go.